# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on MacBook Pro 7.1 (Early 2011) Wifi Issue

Tags: 16.04, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

I am having a hell of a time setting up my Wifi after a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my MacBook Pro 8.1. Using the following command in terminal `sudo lshw -C network` I get the following returned to me:

```
*-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 01
   serial: 78:ca:39:b2:8e:4f
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:d3200000-d3203fff
```

Initially I went to my "Additional Drivers" and enabled the default Broadcom 802.11 driver which enabled my wifi but does not list all of the available networks. I tried to trouble shoot this error through the web and followed some answers on other askUbuntu posts but nothing works. Yes, I have tried installing the drivers manually for BCM4322 via bcmwl-kernel-source... documentation I used [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers). Any help would me much appreciated!!! I have no clue where to go from here.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` And also: `dmesg | grep wl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: As per someone else's comment/and, I too had (but no longer have) an early 2011 MBP, I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS and was using wifi no problems. I never did anything out of the normal to set it up. I will add though, I was never happy with the whole ubuntu experience on apple hardware

Answer (score -1):

in ubuntu terminal as root

```
rmmod b43 bss bcma

insmod wl.ko
```

`wl.ko` is of course your Broadcom driver compiled with `dkms`